# How exactly are HTML links interpreted? Are tab characters special?

Tags: html, xss

If I have a href attribute like `<a href="www.exam ple.com">`, the result of clicking the output link is `www.exam%20ple.com`, which expectedly does not address me to `www.example.com`. I also get the exact same output if I use the no-break space character (U+00A0) or en-quad (U+2000) (again, with `www.exam%20ple.com` as the output). I assume the reason for this is that both are interpreted by HTML as standard white space characters (U+0020) somehow.

Now, what does not make sense is that if I replace the space character instead with a tab character, i.e. `<a href="www.exam    ple.com">`, clicking the link succeeds and directs me right to `www.example.com`. I originally came across this when trying to invoke an XSS stored javascript exploit, where various symbols were escaped and inputs of 'javascript' were sanitized. When I realized that delimiting 'javascript' as 'java  script'    using a tab allowed me to invoke my script, I was delighted, but also very surprised. Why does this happen?

Comment: None of the broken links should work, no idea why the one with the ordinary space should _not_ break that link. The reason why they should not work is simple: "example" and "exam ple" are two different strings. There is not magic gnome there to clean things for you.

Comment: %encoding does *not* apply to the entire URL. Nor is a space or tab (or any other whitespace) valid in a domain name. If it is accepted then there is a client/browser (make sure to specify the exact environment) that "being very lenient" with the input and fixing it up before use; still not a valid URI and as such there is no sanctioned way to accept it.

Comment: How are you even getting a tab into the address bar? Pasting one in IE does nothing, and Chrome converts it to a space.

Comment: @Leeren Do you think you can provide some code that can be looked into?

Comment: @David I use `^V<Tab>` on vim.

Comment: About the javascript getting not refused when there is a blank in the name: following your description I'd say there is a validation logic built into the page you want to hack. Apparently that logic does not recognize the broken string (understandable), but that has nothing to do with html. It is just a question of how the logic is implemented. That the script is executed depends on the situation how you inject it. The declaration of the language might well simply be ignored.

Comment: @0aslam0 http://www.leerenchang.com/tab.html

Comment: @arkascha I think you're right that there may have been some kind of validation logic built into the page, but the exploit was basically inputting a javascript string to be stored in a href of an HTML file, so that clicking on that link would invoke the script (sorry for not clarifying in my post), so I think that has something to do with HTML?

Comment: @user286740 Oh... that makes sense. So in other browsers this would possibly fail? I was using chrome.

EDIT: You're absolutely right. This only works in chrome. Whoops. Thanks for the excellent explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space or tabs are never valid in a domain name, and are only accepted if your client/browser is lenient with the input before using it. Thanks user2864740.